# Coalesce value column on basis of other column without using multiple left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      ID             |    Region        |isProductAvailable|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         USA      |       Yes        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          13         |         Ohio     |       No         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          14         |      Australia   |       Yes        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Now, The use-case that I have is, there is a product, and it's availability is based on hierarchy that is predefined.

**For example:**
USA -> Ohio
Australia -> Sydney

**Case 1**: Now whenever I am querying in this product table, I want to check if it is available in Ohio. Since there is an entry for Ohio. The result should be returned.

**Case 2:** Now whenever I am querying for Sydney, the table does not contain Sydney, so it should search for it's parent in hierarchy specified above. Since there is an entry available for Australian the value for Australia should be returned.

P.S. I have solved this problem with left join and coalesce, but the problem with that is the number of left join increase as the length of specified hierarchy increases.

```
select coalesce(rgn_Oh.isProductAvailable,rgn_USA.isProductAvailable)
 from 
(select t.* from t where region = 'Ohio') rgn_Oh
left join
(select t.* from t where region = 'USA') rgn_USA 
on rgn_Oh.id = rgn_USA.id;
```

Comment: *I have solved this problem with left join and coalesce*. You can try to show them in the question.

Comment: How do you know what the parent region is? I don't see anything in your sample data which establishes a hierarchy. And how would you know to which region a given city belongs to? Do you have another table that maps city names to regions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I would know about it while querying, there is no reference between parent and child region. I would only be querying one region at a time. So for example if I want to query Ohio. I would pass an array of it's inheritance in reverse order. For Ohio, it would be { Ohio, USA }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `order by` for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where region in ('USA', 'Ohio', 'Australia', 'Sydney')
order by (case region
              when 'Sydney' then 1
              when 'Australia' then 2
              when 'Ohio' then 3
              when 'USA' then 4
          end)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Actually this does not solve the problem because the query is supposed to be fired on bulk rows, this query just returns one row only.